# Implementing do while and exit

Tags: java, converters

Being fairly new to Java, I have written this program to calculate various currencies. I would like to ask the user if they wish to repeat the process until the user wishes to exit. Please assist me in this matter. My code so far:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {


    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); 
    DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#0.00");

    String CType, c1 = "US", c2 = "EUR", c3 = "RM", c4 = "SAR"; 
    double CValue , US, EUR, RM, SGD, SAR;


    System.out.println("Welcome to Bonus Calculator");

    System.out.println("Enter any of the following Currencies:"); 
    System.out.print("US\n" +
                     "EUR\n" +
                     "RM\n" +
                     "SGD\n" +
                     "SAR: ");
    CType = input.next();



   if(CType.equalsIgnoreCase("US")){
     System.out.print("Enter Value: ");
     CValue = input.nextInt();

       EUR = CValue * .88;
       RM = CValue * 3.92;
       SGD = CValue * 1.35;
       SAR = CValue * 3.75;

   System.out.print("US = " + formatter.format(CValue) + "EUR =" + formatter.format(EUR) + "RM =" + formatter.format(RM) + "SGD =" + formatter.format(SGD) + "SAR =" + formatter.format(SAR));

   }

   else if(CType.equalsIgnoreCase("EU")){ 
       System.out.print("Enter Value: ");
       CValue = input.nextInt();
       US = CValue * 1.14;
       RM = US * 3.92;
       SGD = US * 1.35;
       SAR = US * 3.75;

   System.out.print("EUR = " + formatter.format(CValue) + " US = " + formatter.format(US) + " RM = " + formatter.format(RM) +" SGD = " + formatter.format(SGD) +" SAR = " + formatter.format(SAR));

   }

   else if (CType.equalsIgnoreCase("RM")){
       System.out.print("Enter Value: ");
       CValue = input.nextInt();
       US = CValue * .26;
       EUR = US * .88;
       SGD = US * 1.35;
       SAR = US * 3.75;

   System.out.print("RM = " + formatter.format(CValue) + " US = " + formatter.format(US) + " EUR = " + formatter.format(EUR) + " SGD = " + formatter.format(SGD) + " SAR = " + formatter.format(SAR));

   }

   else if (CType.equalsIgnoreCase("SGD")){
       System.out.print("Enter Value: ");
       CValue = input.nextInt();
       US = CValue * 0.74;
       EUR = US * .88;
       RM = US * 3.92;
       SAR = US * 3.75;

   System.out.print("SGD = " + formatter.format(CValue) + " US = " + formatter.format(US) + " EUR = " + formatter.format(EUR) + " SAR = " + formatter.format(SAR) + " RM = " + formatter.format(RM));

   }

   else if(CType.equalsIgnoreCase("SAR")){
       System.out.print("Enter Value: ");
       CValue = input.nextInt();
       US = CValue * 0.39;
       EUR = US * .88;
       RM = US * 3.92;
       SGD = US * 1.35;

   System.out.print("SAR = " + formatter.format(CValue) + " US = " + formatter.format(US) + " EUR = " + formatter.format(EUR) + " SGD = " + formatter.format(SGD) + " RM = " + formatter.format(RM));

   }

}
```

Comment: So where's the problem? You already seem to have some grasp on Java, what's the matter with a loop?

Comment: I am confused on where and how to make it ask the user to is they want to enter another value and exit if not. I know from the code is seams like should know this. But im lost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap all your code in a loop and use a boolean variable like `keepRunning` which is initialized to true. At the end of your loop you ask the user (get input from the scanner) then you check whether the input means "yes" or "no" (or in other terms true and false) and set `keepRunning` accordingly (meaning you set it to false if the user chooses "no").

Example:

```
boolean keepRunning = true;
while( keepRunning ) {
  //ask for input, calculate, print - the bulk of your code above

  System.out.println("Would you like to do another? y/n");

  String userInput = ...; //get from scanner, I'll leave this as an excercise for you
  keepRunning = "y".equalsIgnoreCase( userInput ); //you might want to be more lenient here, e.g. also accept "yes" etc.
}
```

Alternatively use `while(true)` and `break;` when the user selects "no".

Example:

```
while( true ) {  //keep running until we stop it from the inside
  //same as above

  ...

  //break the loop if the user didn't select "y"
  if( !"y".equalsIgnoreCase( userInput ) ) {
    break;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I was able to complete and run the program as desired. Have a good day!

Comment: @Try.Coder I'm glad it worked and hope you learnt something as well :) - Btw, don't forget to accept an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Hi check the below code

```
 public static void main(String args[]){
 Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); 
    DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#0.00");

    String CType, c1 = "US", c2 = "EUR", c3 = "RM", c4 = "SAR"; 
    double CValue , US, EUR, RM, SGD, SAR;

    char choice='Y';//modified
    System.out.println("Welcome to Bonus Calculator");
    do{//modified
    System.out.println("Enter any of the following Currencies:"); 
    System.out.print("US\n" +
                     "EUR\n" +
                     "RM\n" +
                     "SGD\n" +
                     "SAR: ");
    CType = input.next();



   if(CType.equalsIgnoreCase("US")){
     System.out.print("Enter Value: ");
     CValue = input.nextInt();

       EUR = CValue * .88;
       RM = CValue * 3.92;
       SGD = CValue * 1.35;
       SAR = CValue * 3.75;

   System.out.print("US = " + formatter.format(CValue) + "EUR =" + formatter.format(EUR) + "RM =" + formatter.format(RM) + "SGD =" + formatter.format(SGD) + "SAR =" + formatter.format(SAR));
   }
   System.out.println("\nDo you which to Continue if Yes press 'Y' other wise press 'N'");//modified
   choice = input.next().toCharArray()[0];//modified
}while(choice!='N');//modified
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use while(true) as

```
public static void main(String[] args) {


        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#0.00");

        String CType, c1 = "US", c2 = "EUR", c3 = "RM", c4 = "SAR";
        double CValue , US, EUR, RM, SGD, SAR;


        System.out.println("Welcome to Bonus Calculator");
        while (true) {

            System.out.println("Enter any of the following Currencies:");
            System.out.print("US\n" +
                    "EUR\n" +
                    "RM\n" +
                    "SGD\n" +
                    "SAR: ");
            CType = input.next();
            if(CType.equalsIgnoreCase("EXIT"))
                break;


            if (CType.equalsIgnoreCase("US")) {
                System.out.print("Enter Value: ");
                CValue = input.nextInt();

                EUR = CValue * .88;
                RM = CValue * 3.92;
                SGD = CValue * 1.35;
                SAR = CValue * 3.75;

                System.out.print("US = " + formatter.format(CValue) + "EUR =" + formatter.format(EUR) + "RM =" + formatter.format(RM) + "SGD =" + formatter.format(SGD) + "SAR =" + formatter.format(SAR));

            } else if (CType.equalsIgnoreCase("EU")) {
                System.out.print("Enter Value: ");
                CValue = input.nextInt();
                US = CValue * 1.14;
                RM = US * 3.92;
                SGD = US * 1.35;
                SAR = US * 3.75;

                System.out.print("EUR = " + formatter.format(CValue) + " US = " + formatter.format(US) + " RM = " + formatter.format(RM) + " SGD = " + formatter.format(SGD) + " SAR = " + formatter.format(SAR));

            } else if (CType.equalsIgnoreCase("RM")) {
                System.out.print("Enter Value: ");
                CValue = input.nextInt();
                US = CValue * .26;
                EUR = US * .88;
                SGD = US * 1.35;
                SAR = US * 3.75;

                System.out.print("RM = " + formatter.format(CValue) + " US = " + formatter.format(US) + " EUR = " + formatter.format(EUR) + " SGD = " + formatter.format(SGD) + " SAR = " + formatter.format(SAR));

            } else if (CType.equalsIgnoreCase("SGD")) {
                System.out.print("Enter Value: ");
                CValue = input.nextInt();
                US = CValue * 0.74;
                EUR = US * .88;
                RM = US * 3.92;
                SAR = US * 3.75;

                System.out.print("SGD = " + formatter.format(CValue) + " US = " + formatter.format(US) + " EUR = " + formatter.format(EUR) + " SAR = " + formatter.format(SAR) + " RM = " + formatter.format(RM));

            } else if (CType.equalsIgnoreCase("SAR")) {
                System.out.print("Enter Value: ");
                CValue = input.nextInt();
                US = CValue * 0.39;
                EUR = US * .88;
                RM = US * 3.92;
                SGD = US * 1.35;

                System.out.print("SAR = " + formatter.format(CValue) + " US = " + formatter.format(US) + " EUR = " + formatter.format(EUR) + " SGD = " + formatter.format(SGD) + " RM = " + formatter.format(RM));

            }
        }

    }
```

when the user typed EXIT it exit from the loop.You have to exit as an option to user.